# Mean and Standard Error of True Percentages (Not Binomial Proportions)

Tags: data-transformation, probit, percentage, back-transformation

In my line of work I occasionally deal with data on the percent lipid of fish fillet (environmental sampling). The question came up today about how to calculate the mean and standard error and possibly obtain a confidence interval for percent lipid from a sample of fish tissue (i.e. a sample where each sampling unit is the tissue of an individual fish). I suggested using a probit transformation to naturally constrain the resulting back-transformed values between 0 and 1. I've plotted the data for a few examples and typically the probit-values look like they can be well-described by a normal distribution, so even without the CLT, I think this is a good approach. But it got me thinking about how well the mean of the probit-transformed data matches up to the mean on the original scale. I'm thinking this is analogous to the well-known fact that the mean of logarithms is not equal to the mean on the original scale.

So any ideas about the relationship between the mean of probit-transformed percentages and percentages themselves? There are lots of question on this topic on CrossValidated, but all the cases I could find were really asking about binomial proportions. Percent lipid of a fish fillet is clearly not binomial.

Comment: Interesting question. For the [log normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), the mean is $e^{\mu + \sigma^2 / 2}$, for the [logit normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution), the mean has no analytic solution, and I suspect that this is also true for the probit normal distribution. In that case, you could always use numerical integration.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's more of a question of curiosity than practical import at this point. For what it's worth, I've toyed around with a simple simulation (simulating 100 random normal with mean equal to qnorm(0.01) and sd = 0.5 [in R: rnorm(100, mean = -2.326348, sd = 0.5)]) and it looks like the backtransformed mean is itself centered on 0.01. But this is pretty cursory.

Comment: Should be around $0.01872845$ based on `integrate(function(x) pnorm(x) * dnorm(x, mean=qnorm(0.01), sd=0.5), lower=-Inf, upper=Inf)`.

Comment: Yep. I was getting a similar number just by taking mean(pnorm(rnorm(...))). The backtransformed mean definitely depends on the standard deviation. Easy to check if you change sd = 0.25, you should get something closer to 0.012.  That's nifty and all, but it doesn't help us a whole lot in the real world of sampling where we only have a sample mean and sample standard deviation.

Comment: Yep, works out to $0.01200751$. But this is quite relevant to the real world -- if you plug in the MLEs of the mean and standard deviation, the value you obtain that way is also the MLE (of the mean on the back-transformed scale).

Comment: That's a very good point. From there I only need to hitch a ride on the assumption train to Asymptopia to pick up some confidence intervals. (Or I suppose I could get bootstrapped MLE estimates). I encourage you to write this up as an answer. I think it's a very good one. I'm also curious about hearing other approaches to summarizing percentage data, so I'll leave the question open. I imagine a beta distribution approach could also be fruitful.